# How to retrieve objectId right after save

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am using Unity and Parse.com for my game development. I am trying to figure out I retrieve the objectId right after save. I have tried this:

```
ParseObject myGame = new ParseObject("Games");
myGame["score"] = 223;
myGame["playerName"] = "Michael";
Task saveTask = myGame.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t => {

    ParseObject theObject = t.Result;
    string newObjectId = theObject.objectId;

});
```

I get an error on the t.Result saying:

```
Type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for `Result' and no
extension method `Result' of type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (are
you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can this be done in this way or another.

any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `this is because Task does not have Result property`

Comment: Ok, so I can not get the ObjectID right back after save then? I need to create a new request then?

Comment: Try just remove line with t.Result and use myGame.objectID in next line

Comment: Ahhh, perfect. That worked. Some the trees gets in the way of the forest ;-)

Comment: @Reniuz  I got an error -  error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Task' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? Could you please help me on this .

Comment: add `using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Answer (score 2):

I was also having problems with retrieving the newly created `ObjectId`. After a few hours (and a lot of searching) I was able to get the below code to work:

```
    public static async Task<string> CreateNewGame()
    {
        string newObjectId = null;

        ParseObject myGame = new ParseObject("Games");
        myGame["score"] = 223;
        myGame["playerName"] = "Michael";

        await myGame.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(
              t =>
              {
                  newObjectId = myGame.ObjectId;
              });

        return newObjectId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove line with t.Result.
use myGame.objectID to get objectId.