# How to retrieve objectId immediately after saving ParseObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am using Unity and Parse.com for my game development. I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the objectId right after I save. I have tried this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;
public class ParseTestScript : MonoBehaviour {
string objectId ;   
ParseObject testObject;

void Start ()
{
    AddTheScore ();
}

void AddTheScore()
    {
    testObject = new ParseObject("ParseTest");
    testObject["score"] = 2332;     
    Task saveTask = testObject.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t => {          

        objectId = testObject.objectID ;

    });
              Debug.Log(objectId );
    }


}
```

I got an error -
   `error CS0246: The type or namespace name "Task" could not be found.Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

I followed this link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248622/how-to-retrieve-objectid-right-after-save#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248622/how-to-retrieve-objectid-right-after-save#_=_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the namespace for Task:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Comment: I tryed your solution but it didn't help me. I am getting same error.

Comment: Sorry. I have to correct my answer. It is: System.Threading.Tasks

Comment: I tried that but this time it showing the following error:

`error CS1061: Type 'Parse.ParseObject' does not contain a definition for 'objectID' and no extension method 'objectID' of type 'Parse.ParseObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Thanx a lot, I have just edited  objectID to ObjectId and that's works fine .